# How to retrieve multiple values returned from solidity with ether.js?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets, returndata

In ethers.js documentation, it is written to retrieve data like below

```
// 'contract' is an instance of Contract made with ethers.js
// Get the current value
let currentValue = await contract.getValue();

console.log(currentValue);
// "Hello World"
```

But my contract returns two value from smart-contract function.
below is the interface of that function

```
function targetNFT() external view returns(address _nftToken, uint256 _nftTokenId);
```

How can I retrieve multiple values returned from smart-contract using ethers.js?

Comment: It will return values as JavaScript array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const result = await contractInstance.yourFunction();

const {0: variable_1, 1: variable_2} = result;
```

Reference: https://blockheroes.dev/js-read-multiple-returned-values-solidity/

Hope it helps.